# How to download a file from a single folder when application hosted on multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, web-garden

I have asp.net application which is going to be deployed on multiple servers (web garden). 
One of my server has **ReadyToExport** folder, where all the file get placed from a different service. When user click on download link i wanted to route that to this single folder(**ReadyToExport**). How do i route all the download request to a single folder. Please suggest a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Share a folder between multiple servers and keep the files there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share a folder between multiple servers and keep the files there?

Comment: how do i map all request to that shared folder ? by creating a common virtual folder